# In an empty tibble, column types change depending on how the first row is added

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I'm developing a Shiny app, part of which needs to edit (change existing values, add new rows) to various tibbles.  A number of tibbles need to be edited, each with different column names and data types. I'd like to use a generic editor.  Each tibble starts off empty.

I create the tibble with zero rows and typed columns.  That works OK.

```
makeTibble <- function() {
  tibble(W=character(), X=numeric(), Y=logical(), Z=structure(NA_real_, class = "Date"))
}
v <- reactiveValues(data=makeTibble())
```

When I add a row and manipulate each column directly, by name, the column types are preserved:

```
observeEvent(input$addDirect, {
    v$data <- v$data %>% add_row(W="Testing...", X=pi, Y=TRUE, Z=as.Date("2020-04-29", origin="1970-01-01"))
  })
```

But that would mean having a different editor for each tibble, and having to edit each editor every time the structure of the corresponding tibble changes (which it will).  So I tried to automate the addition of a new row:

```
newValues <- c("W"="Testing...", "X"=pi, "Y"=TRUE, "Z"=as.Date("2020-04-29")) 
observeEvent(input$addLoop, {
  columns <- v$data %>% dplyr::summarise_all(class) %>% tidyr::gather(variable, class)
  v$data <- v$data %>% add_row()
  for (f in columns$variable) {
    v$data <- v$data %>% mutate(!!f := newValues[f])
  }
})
```

But this converts the type of each column in the tibble to character.  Not what I want. So I try to preserve the type of each column:

```
asTypedValue <- function(value, type) {
  print(paste0("type: ", type, "; value: ", value))
  switch(type, 
         "character"="Testing...",
         "logical"=TRUE,
         "numeric"=pi,
         "Date"=as.Date("2020-04-29", origin="1970-01-01")
   )
}

observeEvent(input$addTypedLoop, {
  columns <- v$data %>% summarise_all(class) %>% gather(variable, class)
  v$data <- v$data %>% add_row()
  targetRow <- nrow(v$data)
  for (col in columns$variable) {
    colClass <- (columns %>% filter(variable  == col))$class
    v$data <- v$data %>% mutate(!! col := ifelse(row_number() == targetRow, asTypedValue(newValues[col], colClass), !! col)) 
  }
})
```

This works for the `character`, `logical` and `numeric` columns, but the `Date` column is converted to `dbl`.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's a `foo` Shiny app to demonstrate what happens.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
    actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
    actionButton("addDirect", "Add row (direct manipulation)"),
    actionButton("addLoop", "Add row (apply loop)"),
    actionButton("addTypedLoop", "Add row (apply loop with typing)")
  ),
  wellPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("tibble")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  newValues <- c("W"="Testing...", "X"=pi, "Y"=TRUE, "Z"=as.Date("2020-04-29"))

  makeTibble <- function() {
    tibble(W=character(), X=numeric(), Y=logical(), Z=structure(NA_real_, class = "Date"))
  }

  v <- reactiveValues(
    data=makeTibble()
  )

  output$tibble <- renderPrint({
    v$data
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    v$data <- makeTibble()
  })

  observeEvent(input$addDirect, {
    v$data <- v$data %>% add_row(W="Testing...", X=pi, Y=TRUE, Z=as.Date("2020-04-29", origin="1970-01-01"))
  })

  observeEvent(input$addLoop, {
    columns <- v$data %>% dplyr::summarise_all(class) %>% tidyr::gather(variable, class)
    v$data <- v$data %>% add_row()
    for (f in columns$variable) {
      v$data <- v$data %>% mutate(!!f := newValues[f])
    }
  })

  asTypedValue <- function(value, type) {
    print(paste0("type: ", type, "; value: ", value))
    switch(type, 
           "character"="Testing...",
           "logical"=TRUE,
           "numeric"=pi,
           "Date"=as.Date("2020-04-29", origin="1970-01-01")
    )
  }

  observeEvent(input$addTypedLoop, {
    columns <- v$data %>% summarise_all(class) %>% gather(variable, class)
    v$data <- v$data %>% add_row()
    targetRow <- nrow(v$data)
    for (col in columns$variable) {
      colClass <- (columns %>% filter(variable  == col))$class
      v$data <- v$data %>% mutate(!! col := ifelse(row_number() == targetRow, asTypedValue(newValues[col], colClass), !! col)) 
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you concatenate in an atomic vector:

```
newValues <- c("W"="Testing...", "X"=pi, "Y"=TRUE, "Z"=as.Date("2020-04-29"))
```

An atomic vector contains elements of the same mode, so everything is coerced to character mode:

```
> newValues
                 W                  X                  Y                  Z 
      "Testing..." "3.14159265358979"             "TRUE"            "18381"
```

Use a list instead:

```
newValues <- list("W"="Testing...", "X"=pi, "Y"=TRUE, "Z"=as.Date("2020-04-29"))
```

(and then use `newValues[[f]]`).

Comment: Stephane, thanks!  That was a wood for the trees moment on my part!  Your suggestion has fixed the problem when I use the `addLoop` option [which gives me a solution I can use in my application], but the addTypedLoop still converts the final column from `Date` to `double`.  What's going on there?